# create method is not working for a tweet - contains error "Couldn't find User without an ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

[image]im making a twitter clone and trying to make it so the users username appears next to their tweet.
Ive made it work through adding a user and a tweet in the seed file, hoever when i add a create,new method and a form it comes up with the error "Couldn't find User without an ID" and highlighting the first line of my create method. not sure what the issue is, thanks.

```html
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :new, :create]

   def index
    @tweets = Tweet.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def show
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    # @tweet = Tweet.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
    @tweet.user = @user
    if @tweet.save
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end
  end

  def edit
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])
    @tweet.update(tweet_params)
    redirect_to tweets_path
  end

  private
  def tweet_params
    params.require(:tweet).permit(:user_id,:content)
  end
end
```

```html
<h1>TWEETS</h1>

<%= simple_form_for [@user,@tweet], id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content, label: "Tweet" %>
   <%= f.input :user %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <% end %>

   <br>

<% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %> <br>
      <%= tweet.content %>
      <%= tweet.user.username %>

    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Check the params. Surely params [:id] is empty.

Comment: @pablo so how do i fix this? thnkas

Comment: looks to me like you have a form for `@user` but the `new` action in your controller doesn't declare `@user`.

Comment: @trueinViso My tweet form is on the index page, so would i need to put a user instance variable in the index method? if so what would it be? thanks

Comment: Yes, and it would be `@user` because that's what you called it in the form.  Any variable you use in the form needs to be declared somewhere, either in the helper, controller, or view.  Rails convention is to declare them in the controller normally.

Comment: @trueinViso ah thanks.  another issue has happened which i believe is a roots issue. i've uploaded a photo to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `@user` in a variable in your index method.

Any variable you use in the form needs to be declared somewhere, either in the helper, controller, or view. Rails convention is to declare them in the controller normally.

I would need to see your `config/routes.rb` file for the error message you are getting in the image, but if you type `rails routes` at the command line, you can see a list of all available routes, when you use:

```
simple_form_for [@user, @tweet]
```

Rails will interpret `[@user, @tweet]` as `user_tweets_path`, and try to submit the form to this path.  That path is defined in your `config/routes.rb` file.

The error is telling you that you have not defined this path in the routes file.  To define this path you can add this line to your routes file:

```
resources :users do
  resources :tweets
end
```